# How to decrease the size of the jumbotron which is used at the footer?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a project where I used jumbotron at the footer. But the height of the jumbotron is high. I used as much as CSS styles to reduce it but i could not do it. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I tried to manually give the height for the jumbotron, but still it's not working.

```
.jumbotron{
         height : 20px;
}
```

I would like to provide the link of the entire code where you can find the actual issue. Just focusing on the footer which is done using jumbotron.
https://jsfiddle.net/1b8gje6f/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added `footer` class to `footer` `div` and added below css

```
.footer.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer.jumbotron p{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
.fakeimg {
  height: 200px;
  background: #aaa;
}

.bgimg {
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.footer.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer.jumbotron p{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="jumbotron text-center bgimg" style="margin-bottom:0;color:white;text-align:left">
  <h1>Raitu Nestam</h1>
  <p>Believe in the future of Agriculture.</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#homePage.html">Raitu Nestam</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="homePage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:black">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="margin-top:11%">

        <li class="active"><a href="#">Add Land Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Show Land Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Weather Details</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>-->
      </ul>
      <!--<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>-->

      <hr class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="background-color:white;border-style:solid;">
      <h2>About us</h2>
      <!--<h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>-->
      <!--<div class="fakeimg">Fake Image</div>-->
      <p>Agriculture is the backbone of the Indian Economy"- said Mahatma Gandhi six decades ago. Even today, the situation is still the same, with almost the entire economy being sustained by agriculture, which is the mainstay of the villages. It contributes
        16% of the overall GDP and accounts for employment of approximately 52% of the Indian population. Rapid growth in agriculture is essential not only for self-reliance but also to earn valuable foreign exchange. .</p>
      <p>Indian farmers are second to none in production and productivity despite of the fact that millions are marginal and small farmers. They adopt improved agriculture technology as efficiently as farmers in developed countries. It is felt that with
        provision of timely and adequate inputs such as fertilizers, seeds, pesticides and by making available affordable agricultural credit /crop insurance, Indian farmers are going to ensure food and nutritional security to the Nation.</p>
      <br>
      <p>It is envisaged to make available relevant information and services to the farming community and private sector through the use of information and communication technologies, to supplement the existing delivery channels provided for by the department.
        Farmers’ Portal is an endeavour in this direction to create one stop shop for meeting all informational needs relating to Agriculture, Animal Husbandry and Fisheries sectors production, sale/storage of an Indian farmer. With this Indian Farmer
        will not be required to sift through maze of websites created for specific purposes.</p><br>
      <p>Once in the Farmers’ Portal, a farmer will be able to get all relevant information on specific subjects around his village/block /district or state. This information will be delivered in the form of text, SMS, email and audio/video in the language
        he or she understands. These levels can be easily reached through the Map of India placed on the Home page. Farmers will also be able to ask specific queries as well as give valuable feedback through the Feedback module specially developed for
        the purpose.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron text-center footer" style="margin-bottom:0;">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`jumbotron` class has `padding` property that makes its size bigger. You can change height to modify it.

```
.jumbotron {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: WORKED LIKE MAGIC!

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code:-

```css
.fakeimg {
    height: 200px;
    background: #aaa;
  }
.bgimg{
         background-color:black;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-position: center;
      }
      .row{
          display: flex;
      }
 
 .jumbotron{
height:auto;
padding:5px 0 !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="jumbotron text-center bgimg" style="margin-bottom:0;color:white;text-align:left">
  <h1>Raitu Nestam</h1>
  <p>Believe in the future of Agriculture.</p> 
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#homePage.html">Raitu Nestam</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="homePage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:black">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="margin-top:11%">
          
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Add Land Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Show Land Details</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Weather Details</a></li>
       <!-- <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>-->
      </ul>
        <!--<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>-->
        
      <hr class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="background-color:white;border-style:solid;">
      <h2>About us</h2>
      <!--<h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>-->
      <!--<div class="fakeimg">Fake Image</div>-->
      <p>Agriculture is the backbone of the Indian Economy"- said Mahatma Gandhi six decades ago. Even today, the situation is still the same, with almost the entire economy being sustained by agriculture, which is the mainstay of the villages. It contributes 16% of the overall GDP and accounts for employment of approximately 52% of the Indian population. Rapid growth in agriculture is essential not only for self-reliance but also to earn valuable foreign exchange. .</p>
      <p>Indian farmers are second to none in production and productivity despite of the fact that millions are marginal and small farmers. They adopt improved agriculture technology as efficiently as farmers in developed countries. It is felt that with provision of timely and adequate inputs such as fertilizers, seeds, pesticides and by making available affordable agricultural credit /crop insurance, Indian farmers are going to ensure food and nutritional security to the Nation.</p>
      <br>
        <p>It is envisaged to make available relevant information and services to the farming community and private sector through the use of information and communication technologies, to supplement the existing delivery channels provided for by the department. Farmers’ Portal is an endeavour in this direction to create one stop shop for meeting all informational needs relating to Agriculture, Animal Husbandry and Fisheries sectors production, sale/storage of an Indian farmer. With this Indian Farmer will not be required to sift through maze of websites created for specific purposes.</p><br>
        <p>Once in the Farmers’ Portal, a farmer will be able to get all relevant information on specific subjects around his village/block /district or state. This information will be delivered in the form of text, SMS, email and audio/video in the language he or she understands. These levels can be easily reached through the Map of India placed on the Home page. Farmers will also be able to ask specific queries as well as give valuable feedback through the Feedback module specially developed for the purpose.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0;">
  <p>Footer</p>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this style="height: 10px;